# C# Wpf DataGrid copy makes Application go in Break Mode

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C# and WPF, i'm using a WPF Datagrid in my Application and on my Work Computer whenever i select some cells and press ctrl + c to copy their content it makes the application go into break mode.

The error i'm getting is

> Blockquote
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'OpenClipboard Failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D0 (CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN))'

This happens whenever i try to do it in the laptop i use at work, however i tried it on my home pc and it works alright, i can copy and then paste the cells's content into excel no problem

Do any of you guys know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CopyingRowClipboardContent` event of the `DataGrid` and within the handler use `Clipboard.SetDataObject()` method. You might have to set the `SelectionUnit` property of the `DataGrid` to `"FullRow"`